# How to install 'fetch' on Nix (instead of using npm install...)?

Tags: javascript, npm, nix

I'm new to Nix. I usually work with react and will run `npm i node-fetch --save`.

As I understand it, Nix can be used for installations like the above, but I have no idea how to get started.

Comment: What is `fetch`? Have you tried searching for "nix install npm package"? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/379842/how-to-install-npm-packages-in-nixos

Comment: Are you aware of [node2nix](https://github.com/svanderburg/node2nix)? Does it not solve your problem?